# MYSQL Search query taking too long in php. Server times out

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, search-engine

I have a table sub_mastersheet with around 50 columns and 30,00,000 entries. I am trying to run a query in it which is taking way too long and the server times out. All the other queries on that table are working perfectly ok.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM sub_mastersheet WHERE contributor_name1 = '$author' OR contributor_name2 = 
'$author' OR contributor_name3 = '$author';
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM sub_mastersheet WHERE CONTAINS(contributor_name1, '$author');
```

None of the above two queries are working and the server always times out. Even on PHP my admin these queries take for about an hour to execute. Can anyone help?

Comment: Indexes on each contributor_name field?

Comment: Do you have any indexes? And do you actually need to retrieve all the columns within that table?

Comment: thats the problem. I dont have any index and so i cannot use full text indexing. And i just need one column. ISBN13

Comment: How many rows are there in the results? what's contributor_name 1, 2, 3 cardinality?

Comment: cardinality is not fixed you could say. They generally vary from normal to very high. and the results depends on the cardinality. Results may vary from over 1 to 11000

Answer (score 0):

Add index on columns (contributor_name2,contributor_name2)

it will improve performance of your query.

Comment: ya. i know that. i was looking if there was any other way other than full text indexing for my search to speed up. Thanks a lot by the way

Comment: which engine your using?